# How to set enumeration in IF loop

Tags: c#, .net

I have an enumeration named "stateType".

```
  enum stateType : int
  {
     Unknown = 0,
     Active = 1,
     Inactive = 2
  }
```

In my function "connection()" showed below i need to display version only at the time of
enumeration "Active".

```
static private void connction()
{
    string hostName = this_event.variableData[0].atr_value;
    string policyGuid = this_event.variableData[1].atr_value;
    string policyVersion = this_event.variableData[2].atr_value;
    string formatVersion = this_event.variableData[3].atr_value;
    string enabled = this_event.variableData[4].atr_value;
    string Version = "0.0.0.0";
    if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6)
    {
        Version = this_event.variableData[5].atr_value;
    }
}
```

How will i do that, i need to set a condition in the

```
if loop(if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6)&& condition )
```

I did this way

```
         if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6 && stateType.Active)
                                {
                                    Version = this_event.variableData[5].atr_value;
                                }
```

i am getting error Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_clientStateType'  D:\P\leaf.cs

Comment: You need to allocate state before you can access it.

Comment: well, you didn't assign anything to `state` by writing `stateType state`, so the error is quickly explained. However, I don't really understand what you want to do...

Comment: Sorry i have edited my question

Comment: On which bases you will decide active state. Write everything clearly

Comment: extreamly sorry There was some misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You're getting error becouse you've never assigned state variable to anything.

If i understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6 && stateType.Active == SPD.SPD_clientStateType.SPD_clientActive)
{
    Version = this_event.variableData[5].atr_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a scenario of knowing what the `StateType` is based on the data you pull up, only after that will you be able to compare it.

Your object model should have something which will point out that its `Active` or `Inactive`

Comment: That already there,if it disconnected it will set to inactive.I did this way         if (this_event.variableData.Length >= 6 && stateType.Active)
                                {
                                    Version = this_event.variableData[5].atr_value;
                                }
But it throwing error Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_clientStateType' D:\P\leaf.cs

Comment: stateType.Active is an enumeration , you need to validate your data against the possible states of the enumeration. this_event.variableData.Length >= 6 this alone should suffice, can you tell me the basis on which Active is set

Comment: extreamly sorry There was some misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

`state` is `null`.  When you declare your `stateType state`, it is of `null` value.  As it's an `enum`, you could use it like `stateType.Active` for example, rather than declaring a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some value for state

```
stateType state = something;
```

Answer (score 0):

`stateType state = stateType.Active;` This is correct.